# Problema com visual studio para compilar

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Começou a me aparecer este problema quando tento executar minha aplicação, nao fiz modificação alguma no sistema alguém sabe o que pode ser isso ?

Managed Debugging Assistant 'BindingFailure' has detected a problem in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe'.

Additional information: The assembly with display name 'Castle.DynamicProxy2' failed to load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 2. The cause of the failure was:

error CS0103: The name '$exception' does not exist in the current context

[image: Erro:]

Comment: eu começaria procurando no código algum lugar que tenha `$exception`

Comment: compila com o f12, talvez o erro esteja em um etapa anterior a esta

Comment: Compilar com f12? f12 é goto defnition não compila nada

Comment: esse $exception nao existe em meu projeto, parece ser algum erro interno do VS, ja pesquisei no projeto inteiro por $exception, nenhum retorno

Comment: Foi resolvido o problema, tivemos que excluir o projeto de minha maquina e baixar do versionador novamente